# List of vulnerabilities in a table with colored border page

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, color, tocloft, border

I want to create a page like the following image, tried to use `tocloft` in order to make the list of vulnerabilities but i can't find a way to generate a table like that. I also created a new enviroment that increments a counter, different for every vulnerability risk, so i can then generate a pie chart.

The idea is to create a single command that adds the vulnerability to this table (incrementing the counter), and changes the color depending on the Risk value.

[image]

```
\newcounter{critical}
\newcounter{high}
\newcounter{medium}
\newcounter{low}
\newcounter{info}
\newcounter{total} 

\newenvironment{vuln}[2][info]{
\stepcounter{#1}
\addtocounter{total}{1}
    Vulnerability: #2
}
{   
}

\begin{vuln}[critical]{Vuln name 1}
    % Vulnerability description
\end{vuln}

\begin{vuln}[low]{Vuln name 2}
    % Vulnerability description
\end{vuln}

\begin{vuln}[high]{Vuln name 3}
    % Vulnerability description
\end{vuln}
```

The vulnerability page will simple contain a table, like the following image, with different tags and descriptions. I already have the page geometry but not the colored border and reference to the table (List of vulnerabilities).

[image]

To summarize, it will be perfect to have something like:

```
% Automatically lists all the vulnerabilities with the color 
% depending on the first parameter of the enviroment [info]
\tableofvulnerabilities

\begin{vuln}[info]{Vulnerability name}
    % This adds the name to the list of vulnerabilities table
    % Depending on the risk the border color will be different ([info])
    \identifier{NCC-007}
    \category{Data Validation}
    % ..
\end{vuln}
```

Thanks in advance

**Edited**, current file with pie chart:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\definecolor{critical}{RGB}{247,147,147}
\definecolor{high}{RGB}{253,104,106}
\definecolor{medium}{RGB}{248,209,148}
\definecolor{low}{RGB}{252,241,152}
\definecolor{info}{RGB}{247,247,247}

\tikzstyle{chart}=[
    legend label/.style={font={\scriptsize},anchor=west,align=left},
    legend box/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size=5pt},
    axis/.style={black,semithick,->},
    axis label/.style={anchor=east,font={\tiny}},
]

\tikzstyle{bar chart}=[
    chart,
    bar width/.code={
        \pgfmathparse{##1/2}
        \global\let\bar@w\pgfmathresult
    },
    bar/.style={very thick, draw=white},
    bar label/.style={font={\bf\small},anchor=north},
    bar value/.style={font={\footnotesize}},
    bar width=.75,
]

\tikzstyle{pie chart}=[
    chart,
    slice/.style={line cap=round, line join=round, very thick,draw=white},
    pie title/.style={font={\bf}},
    slice type/.style 2 args={
        ##1/.style={fill=##1}
    }
]

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\newcommand{\pie}[2][]{
    \begin{scope}[#1]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\curA}{90}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1}
    \def\c{(0,0)}
    \node[pie title] at (90:1.3) {#2};
    \foreach \s in{critical,high,medium,low,info}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\deltaA}{\number\value{\s}/\thetotal*360}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\nextA}{\curA + \deltaA}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\midA}{(\curA+\nextA)/2}

        \path[slice,\s] \c
            -- +(\curA:\r)
            arc (\curA:\nextA:\r)
            -- cycle;
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{max((\deltaA * -(.5/50) + 1) , .5)}

        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
        \path \c -- node[pos=\d]{} +(\midA:\r);
        \end{pgfonlayer}

        \global\let\curA\nextA
    }
    \end{scope}
}

\newcommand{\legend}[2][]{
    \begin{scope}[#1]
    \path
        \foreach \n/\s in {#2}
            {
                  ++(0,-10pt) node[\s,legend box] {} +(5pt,0) node[legend label] {\n}
            }
    ;
    \end{scope}
}

% ENVIROMENT

\newcounter{critical}
\newcounter{high}
\newcounter{medium}
\newcounter{low}
\newcounter{info}
\newcounter{total}

\newenvironment{vuln}[2][info]{
    \stepcounter{#1}
    \addtocounter{total}{1}
    Vulnerability: #2
}
{

}

\begin{document}

\begin{vuln}[critical]{Vuln name 1}
    % Vulnerability description
\end{vuln}

\begin{vuln}[low]{Vuln name 2}
    % Vulnerability description
\end{vuln}

\begin{vuln}[high]{Vuln name 3}
    % Vulnerability description
\end{vuln}


\begin{tikzpicture}
[
    pie chart,
    % {Type}, {color}
    slice type={critical}{critical},
    slice type={high}{high},
    slice type={medium}{medium},
    slice type={low}{low},
    slice type={info}{info},
    pie values/.style={font={\small}},
    scale=2
]

\pie{}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a compilable document, not just fragments

Comment: I'm implementing this in a separated file, doesn't matter if the format is not correct. (Added the file to the post)